# How to pass a JSONObject type value in Java using postman

Tags: java, json, postman

This my Java DTO class

```
public class fieldProviderDTO {

  private JSONObject information;

  public JSONObject getInformation() {
        return information;
    }

  public void setInformation(JSONObject information) {
        this.information = information;
    }
}
```

This is my postman request body that i want to pass.

```
{
"information":{
  "pepsi": {
    "provider": "pepsi",
    "fields": {
      "label": "Account File",
      "type": "file",
      "required": true
    }
  }
}
}
```

But in postman it gives the message as

```
Unrecognized field &quot;pepsi&quot; (class org.json.JSONObject), not marked as ignorable.
```

what can be the reason for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are not mentioned the properties that need to be desterilized in your JSON object, you can check how to use that on by googling POJO with Java.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = getObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

It will ignore all the properties that are not declared.

Comment: If i use this code will it ignore the value from the postman? and will it go as a null value? and do i need to write this code in restController class?